# How to upload image using multipart in Amazon S3

Tags: android, amazon-s3, file-upload, multipart

How to upload file in amazon s3 without credentials but if i have only Presigned url than is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Retrofit2 to upload your image to S3 for your presigned url - the service interface e.g. would look like this:

```
import java.util.Map;

import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Multipart;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Part;
import retrofit2.http.PartMap;
import retrofit2.http.Url;

public interface AmazonS3Service {

    @Multipart
    @POST
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Url String url, @PartMap Map<String,RequestBody> params, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
}
```